# Odds of picking the same number

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate this:

If 3 people have to pick a number between 1 and 9. whats the probability of 1 or more of them picking the same number?

I don't necessarily need an answer as that was just an example, rather I am looking for an equation.

Comment: Interestingly, this is a variant on the Birthday Problem!

Comment: @Newb Ive only seen that problem with determining if there are no duplicates.

Comment: The odds of **one** or more of them picking the same number is 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: What is the probability that none of them get the same number? Think complementary events.

**Edit**: You can think of this probability like this:

It doesn't matter what number the first one chooses, so we don't have to incorporate them in our calculation. The second one has a chance of $\frac{8}{9}$ of hitting a different number and the third one has a $\frac{7}{9}$ chance of hitting a different number than the two previous ones. Thus the result is:
$$\frac{8\cdot 7}{9^2}$$

Comment: (9!/(9 - 3)!)/9^3 ?

Comment: Yes you are correct, although your result is written (and possibly thought of) in a rather complicated manner (I will elaborate in the answer). Now, do you know what a complementary event is and how to calculate it?

Comment: It _does_ lend itself better to a general formula: $\frac{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}}{n^k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}$

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, it seemed to me that since he is confused about a basic question like this, it is in fact *understanding* rather than a formula what he's really after.